# How can I predefine a path for a user logged in via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, directory, users

I'm looking for a way to set something like a default path for a user on my server. So for example I've the user `XYZ`. When I login now with this user on my server, I want to be directly in a defined folder instead on the base dir of this user.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're talking about the current directory the user will be in, not the environment variable `PATH` that governs where programs will be looked for, right?

Comment: Yes, about the file directory the user is in

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :
Add this line in sshd_config

```
ForceCommand { cd 'defined folder/' ; "${SHELL:-sh}" ; }
```